# Opening web-page in CLI

Tags: pi-4, ssh, web-browsers, docker

I have a Gmail API running in a docker container on raspberry pi.  I only access the pi through an SSH session via terminal.  It needs to authenticate me as a user.  This requires that I go to a webpage and login the first time.    How do I open this authenticating session through CLI in a docker container?

All help is appreciated.

[NOVICE]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have configured your docker container to share the port. You can use lynx (a text only browser). It can be installed with the following:

```
sudo apt install lynx
```

You can then open a web page with:

```
lynx google.com
```

There are a number of alternatives to lynx including:

- w3m
- links2
- elinks

There are several other methods of doing this:

- using a headless browser,
- programmatically (using curl, or expect)

but overall the text-based browser is likely to be the easiest.